# basic code needing a fix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written some code:

```
mon=10
a=1
print("You have",mon,"pounds")
bet=input("How much do you want to bet?")
if bet % 1==0:
    bet=int(bet)
else:
    print("Give me a whole number please")
```

But when I answer I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if bet % 1==0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `bet` is a string, not a number. You need to convert it first. When you use `%` on a string, you  are formatting the string, not getting the modulo of a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` returns a string.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input):

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

You should change your code as follows:

```
mon=10
a=1
print("You have",mon,"pounds")
bet=input("How much do you want to bet?")
try:
    bet=int(bet)
    print(bet)
except:
    print("Give me a whole number please")
```

That way the program will try to convert the user intput into an integer - and if that fails it will print "Give me a whole number please"